# TwoWay binding on a DataGrid in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpfdatagrid

I have a WPF DataGrid that I am filling using

```
var allLines = from Lines in ctx.InvoiceLines join PerPs in ctx.ProductsViews on Lines.ProductCode equals PerPs.ProductCode 
               where (Lines.BranchNo == BrNo) && (Lines.Docket == Docket)
               select new { Lines.ProductCode, Lines.Description, Lines.Inv_Quantity, Lines.Grn_Quantity,
                Lines.Inv_Price,Lines.Grn_Price,Lines.Inv_Total, Lines.Grn_Total, Lines.AnalCode,
                Lines.Vat_Rate, Lines.GrnNo,Lines.Comment , PerPs.OuterUnits};

dgGrid.ItemsSource = allLines;
```

I want to use two way binding to update the database when any of the values are changed or when a new row is added. Is that possible?

My xaml code is

```
<DataGrid Grid.Row="3" x:Name="dgGrid" DataContext="{Binding}" FontSize="16" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" 
              VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" SelectionUnit="FullRow" SelectionMode="Extended" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
              SelectionChanged="dgGrid_SelectionChanged" >
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Width="Auto" Header="ProductCode"  Binding="{Binding ProductCode, Mode=TwoWay, Path=IsSelected, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Width="250" Header="Description"  Binding="{Binding Description,  Mode=TwoWay, Path=IsSelected, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" FontSize="14"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Width="61" Header="Inv_Quantity" Binding="{Binding Inv_Quantity,  Mode=TwoWay, Path=IsSelected, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Width="63" Header="Grn_Quantity" Binding="{Binding Grn_Quantity,  Mode=TwoWay, Path=IsSelected, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Width="59" Header="Inv_Price" Binding="{Binding Inv_Price,  Mode=TwoWay, Path=IsSelected, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Width="61" Header="Ord_Price" Binding="{Binding Grn_Price,  Mode=TwoWay, Path=IsSelected, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Width="72" Header="Inv_Total" Binding="{Binding Inv_Total, Converter={StaticResource Currency},  Mode=TwoWay, Path=IsSelected, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Width="74" Header="Grn_Total" Binding="{Binding Grn_Total, Converter={StaticResource Currency},  Mode=TwoWay, Path=IsSelected, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Width="58" Header="AnalCode" Binding="{Binding AnalCode,  Mode=TwoWay, Path=IsSelected, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Width="40" Header="Vat_Rate" Binding="{Binding Vat_Rate,  Mode=TwoWay, Path=IsSelected, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Width="Auto" Header="GrnNo"  Binding="{Binding GrnNo,  Mode=TwoWay, Path=IsSelected, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Width="Auto" Header="Comment" Binding="{Binding Comment, Mode=TwoWay, Path=IsSelected, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Width="Auto" Header="PerP" Binding="{Binding OuterUnits}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGrid.Resources>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="LightSteelBlue"/>
        </DataGrid.Resources>
    </DataGrid>
```

When I run this code all but the PerP column is empty.

I'm quite lost as to how to do the best way so any help will be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All the `Bindings` for your `DataGridTextColumn` besides the "PerP" column are specifying the path twice. For example:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Width="Auto" Header="ProductCode"  Binding="{Binding ProductCode, Mode=TwoWay, Path=IsSelected, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

Here your `Binding` is first specifying the path to be "ProductCode" and then also specifying it to be "IsSelected". Since there is no "IsSelected" property on the objects in the collection that you are binding to the grid, if you run this under the debugger you should see binding errors in the Output window. If you remove the `Path=IsSelected` for those bindings then the column values should be bound correctly.

Your datasource is a collection of an anonymous type so the `var` is necessary, but as others have said two-way binding to that collection isn't going to work for updates back to the source.

Comment: Is there another way to do it that will support two-way binding for updates?

Comment: Yes, by binding to instances of the actual object you want to be updated, which in your case would be the entities tracked by Entity Framework. I'm assuming that ultimately you want changes to be saved back to the database so it makes sense for the updates to affect the EF entities which are doing the change-tracking so that later all changes can be flushed to the database.

Comment: Would you have a link to any sites that would show how this could be done?

Comment: Thanks Steve, that's really good video, I think its exactly what I needed. :)

Comment: @Steve Rowbotham, I get a strange feeling from that video, as if I am in a parallel universe. I don't ever get a data source when I create an EF model. I thought that data sources were just for old-fashioned Table Adapters.

Answer (score 2):

If the "allLines" variable is a `DataTable`, you could just set your DataGrid's `AutoGenerateColumns` to true. 
You also need not to use the "DataContext" property, but "ItemsSource" instead.
Something like this:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=allLines.DefaultView}" ... />
```

To update back the database on changes, call the `Update()` method of your datatable, on a "Save" button click for example.

If "allLines" is not a DataTable, then remove this hellish "var" keyword and tell us the true nature of the variable =)

Comment: When I use ItemsSource the DG is empty. I don't know what Data type allLines actually is

Comment: TBH its pretty clear from the code that the variable on the left side of the assignment isn't a DataTable, so that's not relevant. It's clearly a collection of an anonymous type and so the var is necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Your `allLines` variable is an enumerable of an anonymous type. In C# anonymous types are read-only - the properties cannot be edited, and the changes can't be saved.

Try making your query:

```
var allLines = 
    from Lines in ctx.InvoiceLines 
    join PerPs in ctx.ProductsViews on Lines.ProductCode equals PerPs.ProductCode 
    where (Lines.BranchNo == BrNo) && (Lines.Docket == Docket)
    select Lines;

dgGrid.ItemsSource = allLines.ToList();
```

Comment: Instead of projecting the results of your query into a collection of an anonymous type (i.e. using `new {...}`) select the actual Lines as Paul has shown above since they should be tracking the changes made to them.