# TwoWay Binding ObservableCollection to DataGrid in WPF not working

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, datagrid, two-way-binding

I have this simple DataGrid in my application. Somewhere in the source I bind the `ItemsSource` property of it to an `ObservableCollection<System.Windows.Points>`. So the points are shown in the `DataGrid`. The problem is however I have set the `TwoWay` binding but when changing the point coordinate values in the `DataGrid`, actual point values int the `ObservableCollection` are not changed!

What is going wrong?

```
<DataGrid Name="pointList" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="X" Width="200">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=X, Mode=TwoWay}"></TextBox>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Y" Width="200">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Y, Mode=TwoWay}"></TextBox>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

**Note** I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7847810/twoway-binding-on-a-datagrid-in-wpf) but my problem is different.

Comment: Again: the observablecollection has nothing to do with the data it holds. `System.Windows.Point` is a struct. You cannot use it for this. Create a ViewModel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`System.Windows.Points` is a **struct**. You can't bind its properties correctly.

Why? Because when you do `Text="{Binding X, Mode=TwoWay}"` it will bind the `Text` property of the `TextBox` to the `X` property of the current `DataContext`.

`DataContext` which is... a **struct** `System.Windows.Points` then the `Point` the databinding will modify is not the one you have assigned to `DataContext`.

To solve your problem. Create your own `Point` type using a **class**:

```
public class Point : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private double x;
    public double X
    {
        get { return x; }
        set
        {
            if (x != value)
            {
                x = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("X");
            }
        }
    }
    private double y;
    public double Y
    {
        get { return y; }
        set
        {
            if (y != value)
            {
                y = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Y");
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

and use `UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus` for your binding:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Y, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}"></TextBox>
```

Comment: I use this class but nothing changed! No points update! shouldn't I make some changes to my `DataGrid`. Which event should be used on cell edits?

Comment: @HosseinNarimaniRad So now, _ItemsSource_ is binded to a _ObservableCollection<YourNamespace.Points>_, and it still doesn't work?

Comment: This is the code: `this.dataGrid.ItemsSource = this.points;` points is a ObservableCollection<MyNamespace.Points>. and it is not working.

Comment: I tried to make the binding with code. but it says that `Two-way binding requires Path or XPath.`

Comment: @HosseinNarimaniRad I have found the issue. Look at the end of my post.