# How can I save changes in gridview?

Tags: c#, sql, gridview

I have a gridview in my Project and it shows some data from database. Now I want to change some data and save these changes in database. How can I do it?

Comment: Please add more detailts, what kind of  technology you are using?

Comment: I Work Base on c#. what any other details you want?

Comment: provide more detail.

Answer (score 0):

Due to the fact that you question is not very detailed, i could only give you a schamtic answer. If you are working with WPF, i would use Binding.

1. Create a class which represent your data
2. Bind the class in a collection to your data-grid
3. In the class which represent your datas, you could use INotifyPropertyChanged to get informed when the properties are changed.
4. When a property is changed, you can write the changes back to your database. For example with the raw ADO.NET, Linq2SQL, ...

But there are too many things you did not mention in your question, like:
1. Which database are you using
2. Which UI-Technology are you use (Win Form/ WPF)
3. ..

Here are a few helpful links:

[INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743695(v=vs.110).aspx)

[WPF-Two-Way Binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7847810/twoway-binding-on-a-datagrid-in-wpf)

[Linq To SQL](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26657/Simple-LINQ-to-SQL-in-C)