# In WPF can't get the cell values by using CalendarClosed Method Always showing Null

Tags: c#, wpf

```
This is my model class and Method...

 public class pojo
        {
            public string Prefix { get; set; }
            public int Year { get; set; }
            public int Quarter { get; set; }
            public int SerialNo { get; set; }
            public string From { get; set; }
            public string To { get; set; }
            public string PeriodName { get; set; }
        }
```

By using this model class I enabled the row in datagrid.
 After entering data in row I can not get back the details by using calendar close event.

```
 private void Period_Name(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var rowdata = calendarmstrDG.SelectedItem as pojo;
            var prefix = rowdata.Prefix;
            int year = rowdata.Year;
            int year_twodigits = year % 100;
            string sth = prefix + year_twodigits.ToString();
            pojo obj = (pojo)calendarmstrDG.SelectedItem;
            obj.PeriodName = sth;
        }
```

I can't get the row details by using calendar close event
rowdata always shows null

Comment: Could you share your xaml code?

Comment: Thanks for your reply...I have solved this issue .
 <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Prefix,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
initially I missed the mode and UpdateSourceTrigger properties that's the reason for this issue.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7847810/twoway-binding-on-a-datagrid-in-wpf